# Sending Email Directly From A Mail Server Terminal, How To Manually Specify Source IP?

Tags: mail-server

Trying to send an email to my gmail account via the command line.

I can issue the following command in terminal

```
mail -v -s "test" xxxxx@gmail.com -- -f ooooo@mydomain.com
```

The problem is, the server I'm on is not my domain's mail server, so emails keep ending up in the spambox.

Comment: Usually, you'll want to send e-mails via a "real" mail server, such as your domain's mail server. Specifying a fake IP address is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. And for a good reason: Spammers could then do it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine if you could do this easily, it would be heavily abused.

If they're ending up in spam, then the mail sending process itself is working.

If you just want mails from that server for notification reasons, try adding the email address to your safe senders list, and it should no longer end up in your spam.